# Is there any practical use of reduced rounds of AES

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, block-cipher, key-recovery, related-keys

There are lots of attacks which are on reduced block ciphers. There are practical attack on five rounds of AES-128[five rounds aes broken in six minutes](https://www.isical.ac.in/~space2019/docs/session2_talk3.pdf). I was just wondering if there is any practical application of reduced rounds of AES where less than 10 rounds are used.

Comment: Why there should be, that will be non-standard and insecure. AES quite fast and can be found in some hardware, too.

Comment: 4 rounds of AES make a good 128-bit mixing function

Comment: Reduced rounds version of AES (or other cryptographic primitives) are usually used to mount a practical attack and show research results. Of course the complexity of the attack makes it infeasible on the full AES

Comment: I didn't watch the video yet, but maybe a reduced round AES is mentioned in Jean-Philippe Aumasson's talk "Too much crypto" at this year's Real World Crypto. You can watch it by following "The link for live streaming" on https://rwc.iacr.org/2020/program.html and then scrolling down in the left window "Program" to "Symmetric Cryptography II" and click it.

Comment: @kelalaka i just wanted to know if there is any use of less round aes.

Comment: @j.p. thank you sir for the reference, I will surely see that.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much use for reduced-round AES as a block cipher per se. AES has been carefully designed to provide appropriate security margins and 20 years of cryptanalysis show that they are just right - reducing the number of rounds would make it potentially susceptible to attacks.

On the other hand, the single round function is a very useful transformation that provides good mixing and other provable properties. Moreover, widespread hardware support for the round function (like AES-NI instructions and similar) makes it attractive from the performance point of view.

A good example is a lightweight hash [Haraka](https://tosc.iacr.org/index.php/ToSC/article/view/563) designed for short-input hashing that uses AES round function.